# How to fix a short circuit?

Tags: pcb-design, soldering, kicad

I found two vias that were supposed to connect to two leads of a capacitor were shorted together on a 4-layer PCB. One of the vias is connected to ground. They are not shorted in the KiCAD model (checked multiple times using DRC).

EDIT: After obtaining a of the board and I confirmed that the two vias weren't originally connected. Therefore I am assuming I must have created the short to GND either by overheating that via or some other error. I have resolved to not use that via and instead solder the components together over wire.

FYI - photo not available due to confidential nature of work.

Comment: Where's the photo and the screengrab (without a background grid)?

Comment: Large battery applied to the two different connections.  Probably a hairline short.  Large current will melt short circuit between the two vias.

Comment: Photos. But you can drill out a via manually by putting an V-shaped engraving bit in a pin vice. You can use this to also accurately cut traces. A twist drill bit works in a pinch but an engraving bit is much better. The Gerber is king. What does the Gerber say?

Comment: Another issue may be the solder mask between the two pads was too big to be applied with whatever process you used. Either you need a board house that can do smaller soldermask clearances, or you need to space the via's apart more.

Comment: re-run the design rules check, and check the design rules against the precision you requested from the board maker.  if you opted for "flying probe test" check boards for highly visible "X" marks and reject any that are marked with "X" in a panel the unmarked boards will still be good.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you turn on the design rule checks in KiCad, and that all of the clearances are set as your fabricator recommends.

There'll be a minimum distance between vias, and there'll be a minimum distance between vias and traces.  There's more than that, but those are the two that probably bit you this time around.

What has probably happened is that the vias (or the vias and some trace) were placed closer together than your fabricator can cleanly etch the traces and drill and plate the vias.

KiCad doesn't show a short because it shows you what an ideally fabricated board would look like.

---

Whoops.  Re-read the question.  Shorted to ground.  Same problem, different place, same solution.

As an example, [here are the recommended clearances and trace widths for Eurocircuits (where I have my boards made.)](https://www.eurocircuits.com/blog/kicad-design-rules/)

> 4 Layer Base copper outer 18µ inner 35µ
>
> - Min Track with OL 0.150mm
> - Min Clearance OL 0.150mm
> - Min Track with IL 0.150mm
> - Min Clearance IL 0.150mm
> - Min via Drill Diameter 0.35mm (Tool size)
> - Min via Pad Diameter OL 0.600mm
> - Min via Pad Diameter IL 0.600mm

Check what your fabricator recommends, and set KiCad to use those values - then make sure you've turned on the design rules check.  That's the bug shaped icon on the PCBNEW toolbar.